# How to solve $\int \frac{2x^2-4x+3}{(x-1)^2}\, dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

My book says the answer to $\int \frac{2x^2-4x+3}{(x-1)^2} \, dx$ is $2x-\frac{1}{x-1}+C$ but symbolab says it is $2x-\frac{2}{x-1}+\frac{4}{x-1}-\frac{3}{x-1}-2+C$. Who is correct and how would I get to the answer? I tried to use u-substitution but that doesn't work because the derivative of $2x^2-4x+3$ is not a multiple of $(x-1)^{-2}$ and the derivative of $x-1$ is not a multiple of $2x^2-4x+3$.

Comment: The two answers are equivalent after simplification and a renaming of the constant of integration.

Comment: Here is a series of hints which should help : Divide numerator polynomial by denominator polynomial and integrate the remained by parts

Comment: Well, $$-\frac{2}{x-1}+\frac{4}{x-1}-\frac{3}{x-1}=\frac{-2+4-3}{x-1}=\frac{4-5}{x-1}=-\frac{1}{x-1}.$$ And $-2$ is absorbed by $C$ because $-2$ plus a number is just another number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$2x  \color{red}{-\frac{2}{x-1}+\frac{4}{x-1}-\frac{3}{x-1}} \color{green}{-2+K} = 2x \color{red}{-\frac{1}{x-1}} \color{green}{+C}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $ \int \frac{2x^2-4x+3}{(x-1)^2}\, dx = \int \frac{2\left(x-1\right)^2+1}{\left(x-1\right)^2}\, dx = \int 2+\frac{1}{\left(x-1\right)^2}\, dx = 2x -  \frac{1}{\left(x-1\right)} + C$

Answer (score -2):

Well both the answers are correct. The thing is what is asked in the question. The answers are exactly same.